# Inputting Multiple Data into Text Boxes

Tags: vb.net

I have an integer variable and multiple text boxes. The user enters data into these text boxes and presses a button. The data in these text boxes is saved as variables. Then, the text boxes are reset and the process is repeated, before saving them as variables again. This is done a number of times, from 1 to the integer variable. How can I do this, so that I can put each variable from the text boxes into an array so they can be sorted and searched?
If you have any questions, please ask.

These are the variables. `noofcompetitors` is entered by the user.

```
Dim noofcompetitors As Integer
Dim surname(noofcompetitors) As String
Dim firstname(noofcompetitors) As String
```

The user then inputs surname and firstname into text boxes a `noofcompetitors` amount of times. The data from the text boxes are inserted into the arrays on button click.

I'll try to explain what I've got. The user enters the integer variable into a text box, showing several new text boxes. From there, the user enters data into these text boxes (e.g. surname, firstname). These are saved into individual variable arrays at a button click. The text boxes are reset and the user enters data into the text boxes again. These are then saved into the array. This continues until the data is entered the integer variable number of times (e.g. 25 times). I'm not sure how I enter these into individual variable arrays, as the number of times they are entered changes

Comment: G'day mate and welcome to Stack Overflow, Could you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I'll try to explain what I've got. The user enters the integer variable into a text box, showing several new text boxes. From there, the user enters data into these text boxes (e.g. surname, firstname). These are saved into individual variable arrays at a button click. The text boxes are reset and the user enters data into the text boxes again. These are then saved into the array. This continues until the data is entered the integer variable number of times (e.g. 25 times). I'm not sure how I enter these into individual variable arrays, as the number of times they are entered changes.

Comment: Sorry, can you post your code please, only the important parts but.

Comment: These are the variables. noofcompetitors is entered by the user.                          `Dim noofcompetitors As Integer
                Dim surname(noofcompetitors) As String
                        Dim firstname(noofcompetitors) As String`                                    The user then inputs surname and firstname into text boxes a `noofcompetitors` amount of times. The data from the text boxes are inserted into the arrays on button click.

Comment: Sorry, its best to edit your main question with your code,

Comment: I've added what I've said so far

Comment: ok, from what I can understand without looking at your source code, you want to keep adding whats in the textboxes to an array, and then sort them? how would you like to sort them? alphabetically? by length?

Comment: I have an equation I will perform to sort them. What I need help with is writing the data in the text boxes to the array, but as the number of variables I will add to the array keeps changing I need to know how to keep adding data through the text boxes and have them placed into the arrays until I reach the `numberofcompetitors` variable. If there is a better way to do it, please let me know, because I'm becoming stuck.

Comment: Use generic lists instead of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using generic lists instead and using an if statement to check if number of competitors added are more than they have asked for. I obviosuly didnt know what your button was called or the textboxes so i made up names for them you can replace. Is this what you sort of looking for?

```
'These are your global variables
Dim noofcompetitors As Integer
Dim surname As List(of string)
Dim firstname As List(of string)

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
  If (surname.count - 1) < noofcompititors Then
   surname.add(tbSurname.text)
   firstname.add(tbFirstname.text)
  Else
   Msgbox("Number of amount compititors succeeded") 'or whatever you want to do here
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, that worked quite well! Thanks for your help. Additionally, how can I format, sort and access this list, as I'm unfamiliar with this function?

Comment: I would suggest looking at this [website](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-list-vbnet) Lists in my opinion more useful as you can simply do `surname.sort()` which would sort it alphabetically for example. You can use Linq more effectively with Lists. There's tonnes of stuff on the internet to read up on them. :)

Comment: Though i suppose you got be careful with having surnames and firstnames in separate lists when sorting them

Comment: Could I sort this list using a specific equation/function?

Comment: Depends on how you want to sort it

Comment: I want to sort it by a score calculated from the variables entered into the lists. Would that be possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. But I would need more information to go by and I think that would probably be a new question. Read up on lists and see if you can find some way of sorting it. I'm assuming you have a way to link each name with a score.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Collections.Generics

Public Class Form1

    Dim GoThrough As Integer = 0 'This will go through the Array each time you click the add button
    Dim MyArray As Char() = New Char(4) {}

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click

        MyArray(GoThrough) = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
        ResizeArray()
        GoThrough += 1
        MyArray(GoThrough) = CStr(TextBox2.Text)
        ResizeArray()
        GoThrough += 1
        MyArray(GoThrough) = CStr(TextBox3.Text)
        ResizeArray()
        GoThrough += 1
        MyArray(GoThrough) = CStr(TextBox4.Text)
        ResizeArray()
        GoThrough += 1
        MyArray(GoThrough) = CStr(TextBox5.Text)
        ResizeArray()
        GoThrough += 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResizeArray()

        'Array Resizing

        For i As Integer = 0 To MyArray.Length - 1
            MessageBox.Show(MyArray(i).ToString()) 'Remove this message,its just for testing Purposes
         Next

        Array.Resize(MyArray, 3)

        For i As Integer = 0 To MyArray.Length - 1
            MessageBox.Show(MyArray(i).ToString()) 'Remove this message,its just for testing Purposes
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You should explain your code and why you feel it will fix the OPs problem rather just doing a code dump.

Comment: In the code dump above the gothrough variable is used to as the index for for inserting textbox data to the array and the ResizeArray function resizes the array after a new array index is needed